# fast comparison of large amount of list of lists

Tags: python, list, data-structures

Comparing list of lists has been posted about before but the python environment that I am working in cannot fully integrate all the methods and classes in numpy. I cannot import pandas either.

I am trying to compare lists within a big list and come up with roughly 8-10 lists that approximate all the other lists in the big list.

The approach I have works fine if I have <50 lists in the big list. However, I am trying to compare at least 20k lists and ideally 1million+. I am currently looking into itertools. What might be the fastest, most efficient approach for large data sets without using numpy or pandas?

I am able to use some of the methods and classes in numpy but not all. For example, numpy.allclose and numpy.all do not work properly and that is because of the environment that I am working in.

```
    global rel_tol, avg_lists
    rel_tol=.1 
    avg_lists=[]
    #compare the lists in the big list and output ~8-10 lists that approximate the all the lists in the big list
    for j in range(len(big_list)):

        for k in range(len(big_list)):

            array1=np.array(big_list[j])
            array2=np.array(big_list[k])
            if j!=k:
            #if j is not k:  

                diff=np.subtract(array1, array2)
                abs_diff=np.absolute(diff)

                #cannot use numpy.allclose
                #if the deviation for the largest value in the array is < 10%
                if np.amax(abs_diff)<= rel_tol and big_list[k] not in avg_lists:

                    cntr+=1
                    avg_lists.append(big_list[k])
```

Comment: Can you or can you not use numpy?  You say you can't, but it sure does look like your code is using numpy!

Comment: using `j is not k` is an error. Use `j != k`. what is `plane_array1`?

Comment: As mentioned in the OP, I "cannot fully integrate all the methods and classes in numpy". I can use some numpy methods and classes but not all of them. In one of the comments, I note that I cannot use `numpy.allclose`

Comment: Daniel, thank you for pointing out the errors. I edited the code accordingly

Comment: Have you considered implementing a `Python` extension in `C`?

Comment: unfortunately, the Python setup that I have is not very flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, it looks like what you're aiming at is a clustering operation (i.e. representing a set of N points via K < N cluster centers). I would suggest a [K-Means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) approach, where you increase K until the size of your clusters is below your desired threshold.

I'm not sure what you mean by "cannot fully integrate all the methods and classes in numpy", but if scikit-learn is available you could use its [K-means estimator](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html). If that's not possible, a simple version of the K-means algorithm is [relatively easy to code from scratch](https://datasciencelab.wordpress.com/2013/12/12/clustering-with-k-means-in-python/), and you might use that.

Here's a k-means approach using scikit-learn:

```
# 100 lists of length 10 = 100 points in 10 dimensions
from random import random
big_list = [[random() for i in range(10)] for j in range(100)]

# compute eight representative points
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
model = KMeans(n_clusters=8)
model.fit(big_list)
centers = model.cluster_centers_
print(centers.shape)  # (8, 10)

# this is the sum of square distances of your points to the cluster centers
# you can adjust n_clusters until this is small enough for your purposes.
sum_sq_dists = model.inertia_
```

From here you can e.g. find the closest point in each cluster to its center and treat this as the average. Without more detail of the problem you're trying to solve, it's hard to say for sure. But a clustering approach like this will be the most efficient way to solve a problem like the one you stated in your question.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate this feedback. To clarify on the numpy subject, I am using a rather complicated setup of a python virtual environment with a specific Python interpreter. Some methods/classes (like numpy.subtract) work fine while others (like numpy.all) do not. It is the virtual environment and Python interpreter that are causing the issues and there is no quick easy fix. I will see if I can import scikit-learn (fingers crossed!). Thanks again!

Comment: Are you using pypy + numpypy? In that case, scikit-learn and other tools are not going to work, and you're stuck coding up these kinds of algorithms from scratch.

Comment: thanks again for all the feedback. unfortunately, i am unable to import scikit-learn so I think I will have to write this algorithm from scratch